# In App Purchase not working in live environment iOS

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have implemented In App Purchase which working fine in sandbox environment. I am getting receipt from the sandbox server & sending the details to my own server. When user purchasing any package from live app the amount get deducted but due to some issue can't able to save the details in my own server.

It might because I am not getting any receipt or any other reason that I can't able to find & debug as well. So, I just keen to know that is there any way to solve it out.

Comment: Could you post some code that could show what you are doing at the end of purchase. Is your network environment well defined when outside the sandbox ( Internet address vs local address, ...)

Comment: @PtitXav Do you have any idea how can I track what is the reason of not getting receipt after successful purchase in a live app.